# Azure function: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase

Tags: unity-container, azure-functions

I've created an Azure function and have created a class which implements the `IExtensionConfigProvider` interface with the `Initialize` method to do some "bootstrapping" on "start up". Included in the bootstapping is some Unity registration where I use the `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` to complete convention registrations.

However I'm getting `This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase` error when `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` is called. I've even put this method in the actual function code (so not "start up") and still get this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do something that's not supported. IExtensionConfigProvider.Initialize() is a very protected context and you can't really control when it runs - it should just be used to register binding rules.  Azure Functions does not yet have dependency injection support.

1. If you have code that you want to run early, you could put it in a static constructor.
2. If you want more control, you could switch to using the underlying WebJobs SDK (which allows you to own the main function). Functions is layered on top of WebJobs SDK.